# How do you add extra string in after a variable?

Tags: python

```
k=int(input("enter a number"))

for i in range (1,11):
result = i * k
print (i, "x", k + "is" , result)
```

if i take out the "is" it shows this:

```
    1 x 7 7 
    2 x 7 14
    3 x 7 21
    4 x 7 28
    5 x 7 35
    6 x 7 42
    7 x 7 49
    8 x 7 56
    9 x 7 63
    10 x 7 70
```

when i add the "is" it shows this:

```
 enter a number7
   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Windows/System32/cool.py", line 7, in <module>
    print (i, "x", k + "is" , result)
    TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

but i want it to look like:

```
 1 x 7 is 7...
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot concatenate a string with a number as you do when you do `k + "is"`.

Either convert `k` to a string by using the `str` function or use string formatting instead which is better and safer to use

```
print "{0} x {1} is {2}".format(i, k, result)
```

or if you want to name your variables

```
print "{i} x {k} is {result}".format(i=i, k=k, result=result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is this part:

```
k + "is"
```

You cannot add a string and integer together. Try writing a simple program with `5 + "X"` and you will see the same issue. To resolve this, make sure you convert your integer to a string, before adding to another string.

```
print (i, "x", str(k) + "is" , result)
```